# Show image in listview in adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, bitmapimage

Text information is displayed correctly, but I am having difficulty editing and displaying the photo.
After you hit the Edit button, all the information is displayed edittext, the image is not displayed imageview
please guide me

```
package com.rezam19975.myimage1;
```

class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<InfoData> employees;

MyListAdapter(Context context, List<InfoData> employees){
    this.context = context;
    this.employees = employees;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return employees.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return employees.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return employees.get(i).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
    TextView txtName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_employee_name);
    TextView txtPhone = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_employee_phone);
    TextView txtAddress = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_employee_address);
    Button btnEdit = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
    Button btnDelete = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    ImageView imgview = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgview);

    txtName.setText(employees.get(position).getName());
    txtPhone.setText(employees.get(position).getFamily());
    txtAddress.setText(employees.get(position).getDescription());
  //  byte[] infoimage = ;
  //  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(infoimage, 0, infoimage.length);
   // imgview.setImageBitmap(employees.get(position).getImage());


    btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((Manage) context).editEmployee(employees.get(position));
        }
    });

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new MyDB(context).deleteEmployee(employees.get(position));
            employees.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return rowView;

}
```

}

code java class:

```
 public void editEmployee(InfoData infoData) {
    findViewById(R.id.EdtID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(onEditEmployeeSubmit);
        byte[] infoimage = Manage.image;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(infoimage, 0, infoimage.length);
        EdtNAME.setText(infoData.getName());
        EdtFAMILY.setText(infoData.getFamily());
        EdtDESCRIPTION.setText(infoData.getDescription());
        ImgViewOrgs.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        seletcedEmployeeId = infoData.getId();

}
```

after click item in listview All information is displayed except for the photo

Comment: try using Glide for showing images

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: Please use recycler-view and Picasso or glide.